# Linux shell script "No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have created a shell script to complete 3 simple tasks (zip a directory, rename the final file and delete the source directory). The script source is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $2 == *"/data/"* ]]
then
    src= $2"/*";
    dest= $1".zip";

    # Just for test
    echo $src;

    # Commented for now
    #zip -r -j $dest $src
    #mv $dest $1
    #rm -rf $2
else
    echo "Invalid arguments";
fi
```

When I run the script above with these parameters I have with error:

```
./scriptzip.sh /data/file-new /data/file-old

./scriptzip.sh: line 4: /data/file-old/*: No such file or directory
./scriptzip.sh: line 5: /data/file-new.zip: No such file or directory
```

How can prevent the shell to test a variable for "directory like" string? There is any way to skip that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space is significant in the shell, as that's what divides the tokens in commands such as `echo foo bar` or worse `rm -rf /some/where /`. Hence, assignment must not include spaces around the `=`:

```
foo=/etc/*
echo $foo
```

Variables may also need quoting, depending on exactly what you want to happen for here glob expansion and also word splitting (incorrect word splitting to `rm` can result in unexpected (and hilarious) filesystem cleanups).

```
echo "$foo"
```

Comment: On quoting: it's best to leave the wildcards out of variables, and then double-quote variable references. E.g. `src="$2"; dest="$1.zip"; zip -r -j "$dest" "$src"/*`. Also, you really really should check for any errors (especially on the `zip` command), and if there are any *do not delete the source files*.

Comment: Thank You Gordon, I agree with you. In fact this script (now in production) has changed a lot from this example (even to avoid any stupidity from "rm -rf" ). Also you have right about the source file deletion but in this case I needed an "atomic operation". And of course, the script itself will called carefully by PHP with "well checked" inputs. I had to use a shell script to make these background tasks ( **exec( "nohup " . $cmd . " > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!", $out );** ) and get the PID of this process to use later (To check the status: exec( "ps -p " . $pid, $out ); ). Thank You again.